# Porque levam certas palavras paroxítonas acentuação na sílaba tónica?

Tags: ortografia, acentuação

Considerando que por exemplo as palavras *distribuírem* e *jóia* são paroxítonas, e que em Português as palavras sem acentuação são por defeito paroxítonas, porque razão levam acentuação? Qual a regra para os ditongos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se bem entendo, um ditongo "ambíguo" (i.e. composto de "i" e "u") na sílaba tônica paroxítona é, por padrão, decrescente. É o caso, por exemplo, das palavras "cuia" e "fortuito", que são pronunciadas "cúia" e "fortúito". Se "distribuírem" não fosse acentuada, então quem a lesse pronunciaria "distribúirem".

Quanto a "joia", acredito que a regra servia para enfatizar que o "i" não é tônico. De qualquer forma, no Novo Acordo Ortográfico, "joia" não recebe mais acentuação. Em tritongos como este, o acento é usado apenas se o "i" for tônico (como em "doía"), para enfatizar que não é uma semivogal.

Comment: Joia não leva acento? Mas então devia-se ler "jôia", como joio ou poia... :(

Comment: @ANeves no Novo Acordo, não há acento, até onde sei e pude constatar. Por exemplo, https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990#Mudan.C3.A7as_em_todos_os_pa.C3.ADses_lus.C3.B3fonos. Acredito que a distinção entre vogal aberta e fechada agora nao pode ser vista na escrita :-/

Comment: @ANeves O Brandizzi tem razão: vê [Acordo Ortgráfico 1990, base IX, ponto 3](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990), «Não se acentuam graficamente os ditongos representados por ei e oi da sílaba tónica/tônica das palavras paroxítonas [...] tal como apoio (subst.), Azoia, boia». O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/joia) também te dá as grafias atual e antiga. Tu irias gostar da grafia usada pelo Cândido de Figueiredo no «Nôvo Diccionário da Língua Portuguêsa» de 1899, onde ele escreve *fórma* e *fôrma* e coisas assim para não haver cá confusões :)

Comment: A jóia agora virou fêmea ou "a mulher" do joio. E isto não é possível!

Answer (score 0):

Bem. Quando aprendi regras de acentuação, aprendi que o "i' e o "u"  como segunda vogal de um hiato sempre leva acento.  tra-í-ra;    Sa-ú-de,    dis-tri-bu-í-rem.  Ou seja. Nesta palavras não há ditongos, e sim, hiatos. E o "I" e "u" como segunda vogal do hiato sempre é acentuado.

No caso de jóia, não é um tritongo. Tritongo são em palavras como Uruguai, onde as três vogais  não se separam.  Jó-ia, uma paroxítona  terminada em ditongo crescente "ia"  e de acordo com as regras do português, toda paroxítona terminada em ditongo crescente deve ver acentuada. IndependêcIA, malícIA, sérIE, Todas terminam em ditongo crescente, daí a razão do acento

Comment: Carlos, bem-vindo ao site. Oficialmente, a separação silábica é *joi.a*, ditongo decrescente seguido de vogal simples, e na grafia oficial em vigor não leva acento gráfico.